# How to clickable button on the basis of select and fetch data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

At what I am trying to do is I have one table in data and I want to make in my below code when I select checkbox and click submit button then call api and fetch the data how can we do that any help on this.

My code here
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-o8tu5

I have this api
https://mocki.io/v1/b512f8b8-64ab-46e4-9e0c-9db538a0ad9e

Can anyone suggest how to call api when I selcect checkbox row and then click button then data is fetched.

Can anyone help me out this

Comment: Anybody plz help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to do the following :- fetching data from the api if the radio button is checked & after button press

```
    import React,{useState} from "react";

const Test=()=> {
    const [fetcheddata, setFetchedData]=useState([]);
    const handleClick=async()=>{

        if(document.getElementById("check").checked = true){
        console.log("Checking ");
          await fetch("https://mocki.io/v1/b512f8b8-64ab-46e4-9e0c-9db538a0ad9e")
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            setFetchedData(data);
          });
    
        } 
            else{
                // do anything you want to do if checkbox is not selected :D
                console.log("nothing")
            }
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          className="table-employee"
          style={{ marginTop: "20px", border: " 1.5px solid darkgray" }}
        >
          <table className="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Select</th>
                <th scope="col"> LOAD DATE</th>
                <th scope="col"> FILE DATE</th>
                <th scope="col"> SERVICE</th>
                <th scope="col"> PROVISIONER CODE </th>
                <th scope="col"> DESCRIPTION</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input id="check" type="radio" preventdefault  
                  name="select" />
                </td>
       
                <td>dfgrty</td>
                <td>fgfg</td>
                <td>fgfg</td>
                <td>erer</td>
                <td>uuio</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        
        </div>
        <div className="btn-submit">
          <button
            className="btn btn-primary"
            style={{ marginRight: "30px" }}
            // type="submit"
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            submit
          </button>
          {fetcheddata?.map(i=>{
              return(
                  <>
                  <p>{i.id}</p>
                  <img style={{width:"100px"}}src={i.url} alt="image"/>
                </>
              )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  
}
export default Test;
```

I have converted your class component into functional component(it makes things lot simpler)